# Domain without hosting - possible to redirect with DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, redirect

I have a domain (A) without webhosting and I have different domain with hosting (B). I have no experience with that but I guess it should be possible to redirect DNS with A directly to B. In domain administration there is a possibility to change AAAA DNS or ctname and some other settings.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Depends on the details of your hosting -- if your existing hosting for B is a name-based vhost, for instance, that makes it a rather different animal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're domain provider hosts your host records (I know namecheap.com provides this) you can set up a URL Redirect within there. Otherwise you will need a DNS server to do the redirecting, you can check out http://freedns.afraid.org/ to do it for free

Answer (score 1):

A DNS [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) record says that one name is an alias for another, so you could set up a CNAME record for domain A to point to the domain name for B.

Alternatively, a DNS `A` maps a domain name onto an IP address, so you could set the A record for domain A to point to the IP address of your webhosting (as I expect domain B currently does). Note that in this solution A does not point to B; A and B both point to the same IP address.

Both these actions effectively make the two domain names point to the same website. If you want to run two different websites from the same hosting account, I think talking to your hosting provider will be the best idea, as they will know how best to do that on their infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

If your domain and hosting (B) both are with GoDaddy, here is the answer to your question - http://www.letswebify.com/blog/digitalmarketing/how-to-point-multiple-domain-names-to-single-godaddy-hosting-space-account.html

Comment: Please, add a summary of the link you're pointing to.

Comment: Link is dead, please update it.